# SoftLayer API: Does VSI flavor based order support specifying image_id

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We want to programatically order VSI using the flavor (for example. Balanced type),  however instead of using the standard os_code, we want the VSI to be created from a public image template (ie.  CentOS7-ChangeStable).   From the following doc it seems to be possible.

http://softlayer-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/SoftLayer/managers/vs.html

However I tried but got the following error:

```
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue): Invalid value provided for 'blockDevices'. Block devices may not be provided when using an image template.
```

Using slcli is failing as well with a different error:

```
# slcli vs create --hostname testvsi --domain vmonic.local --flavor BL2_4X8X100 --image 1cc8be72-f230-4ab9-b4b2-329c3e747853 --datacenter tok02 --private
This action will incur charges on your account. Continue? [y/N]: y
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Order is missing the following category: Operating System.
```

Please advice whether using "image_id" with "flavor" is supported in SL API / python API.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an issue with the API, the python client uses the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_virtual_guest/createObject method to create the VSI using RESTFul the same request would be something like this:

```
POST: https://$USERNAME:@APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject

Payload:
{
    "parameters": [{
        "datacenter": {
            "name": "tok02"
        },
        "domain": "softlayer.local",
        "hourlyBillingFlag": true,

        "blockDeviceTemplateGroup": {
            "globalIdentifier": "1cc8be72-f230-4ab9-b4b2-329c3e747853"
        },
        "hostname": "rcabflav",
        "privateNetworkOnlyFlag": true,
        "supplementalCreateObjectOptions": {
            "flavorKeyName": "BL2_4X8X100"
        }
    }]
}
```

and you will get the same error, I reported this error in Softlayer, if you want you can submit a ticket in softlayer and report it as well.